# Panda create csv with dictionary column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I am try to create csv file with dictionary column but when I read it, that column is string not dictionary data type.

```
splittrain.to_csv("SQuAD_tain.csv",index=False)
```

splittrain is DataFrame. answers column have a dictionary data. when check type by using `type(splittrain['answers'][0])`, it give `dict`.

`splittrain['answers'][0]` - `{'text': ['abcd'], 'answer_start': [1]}`

when read csv file after save, it give string data.

```
finaldf = pd.read_csv("SQuAD_tain.csv")
```

When check type using `type(finaldf['answers'][0])` it give `str`.

I can not access `finaldf['answers'][0]['text']` data. It give following error message.

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

When I try `finaldf['answers'][0]`, it give `'{'text': ['abcd'], 'answer_start': [117]}'`.

When I use following code, I can access text data in dictionary.

```
import ast

finaldf = pd.read_csv("SQuAD_tain.csv", converters={'answers': ast.literal_eval})
```

`finaldf['answers'][0]['text']` give `abcd`.

I need CSV file with dictionary `answers` column. How to solve this issue?

Comment: `I need CSV file with dictionary answers column.` - text file is always strings, so not possible,

Comment: which mean I can not create dictionary data type column after save. All convert to str.

Comment: Exactly you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Data in `csv` are always `string`s:

If need save dtypes, one alternative is use [`to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) / [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html) or [`to_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) / [`read_parquet`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html):

```
splittrain.to_pickle('SQuAD_tain.pkl')

splittrain = pd.read_pickle('SQuAD_tain.pkl')
```

Comment: hugging face load_dataset support csv, json, txt or parquet file types. How to address this issue?

Comment: @Ind - then use parquet , give me a sec.